# Bluestacks error specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name :Minimumsize

Tags: bluestacks

When I am opening BlueStacks Player it shows an error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: MinimumSize

[image]

I don't want to reinstall BlueStacks because I have some important documents in it.

Comment: A [simple web search](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bluestacks+app+player+specified+argument+was+out+of+range) gives tons of information on this. Have you tried the [answer on BlueStack's support site](https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206892906-Specified-argument-was-out-of-range-of-values-error) already?

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing the screen resolution? That is the only fix that seems to work for this error. When asked for Bluestacks help, they asked to update the Bluestacks player, but that did not work. However, changing the screen resolution did the trick.

Source http://www.technicalnotes.org/common-bluestacks-errors-and-fixes/